# How to make sections into sentence case

Tags: sectioning, capitalization

I would like my sections (and potentially subsections) to be in "sentencecase" no matter how I type them. I am happy with the way the `\MakeSentenceCase` macro from the [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package converts text with arbitrary capitalization into sentencecase. I am having difficulty integrating this into the `\section` macro.

My first attempt was to redefine `\section` to be

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\MakeSentenceCase}}
```

but this fails because the first token (or something like that) to `\MakeSentenceCase` is not the first token of the text of my section heading, but rather related to the numbering and indenting. The following method works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\let\sectionOrig\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{\@sectionStar}{\@sectionNoStar}}%
\newcommand{\@sectionNoStar}[2][\relax]{\ifdefstring{\relax}{#1}{%
  \sectionOrig{\MakeSentenceCase{#2}}%
}{%
  \sectionOrig[#1]{\MakeSentenceCase{#2}}%
}}
\newcommand{\@sectionStar}[1]{\sectionOrig*{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{sections SHOULD BE IN {SENTENCECASE}}
\end{document}
```

by completely redefining the `\section` command. I have tried to take care of the starred and unstarred forms and optional arguments, but I am worried that this approach is going to cause problems someplace else.

I guess I have 3 questions. First, is it reasonable to expect LaTeX to automatically handle the capitalization of sections. Second, is my approach reasonable. Third, is there a better approach (or an already existing package).

Comment: Sorry, but it's not reasonable to expect LaTeX knows English (or any other language).

Comment: @egreg "to expect LaTeX _to know_ the English (or any other) language" ? ;-) [I am not sure ;-) -- will presumably soon delete this comment for fear of bringing shame on me... ]

Comment: @jfbu In this case, "expect LaTeX knows" is short for "expect that LaTeX knows". The word "that" can often be dropped. Your version is correct too.

Comment: @jfbu (shame shame shame—learn Italian `;)`) Also, I don't see this as unreasonable as it is asked—but I would counter-ask (?) if this is what you *really* want; if any acronyms appear in your sections, they may be downcased (depending on how `\MakeSentenceCase` handles groups).

Comment: @SeanAllred I am not sure I really want it, but I thought I would try it. The `\MakeSentenceCase` only works on brace level 0 so as long as I group my acronyms it is fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easy using the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.
With the `explicit` option (p. 8, sec. 3.7), we can use an (I think) arbitrary transformation on the sectioning title stored as `#1`.
With this knowledge, the rest becomes a piece of cake:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % two-column used to get everything onto one page
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % note the `explicit` option

\titleformat{\section} % The normal, unstarred version
    {\Large\bfseries}{}{2ex}
    {\thesection. \MakeSentenceCase{#1}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless} % The starred version; note the `numberless` key
    {\Large\bfseries}{}{2ex}
    {\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\section{I am a Section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{I am An Other section}
\lipsum[2]
\section*{I am an UnNumBeReD section with {ACRO}-nyms}
\lipsum[3]
\section{I am a Section}
\lipsum[4]
\section{I am An Other section}
\lipsum[5]
\section{More {ACR}-o-{NYM}s!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note that this solution can be easily applied to the other sectioning commands by just replacing `\section` and `\thesection` appropriately.)

---

As for your other questions:

- as long as you are *not* expecting LaTeX to achieve/follow fancy casing rules (such as title-casing) for arbitrary languages, then you are *fine*.  TeX knows the relationships between all of the letters (uppercase/lowercase) and can swap between them where necessary.  So-called 'dumb' control of casing (e.g. capitalize first letter, lowercase the rest) is completely reasonable.
- Your approach is reasonable if it works well, but it is usually better to build upon an existing package (e.g. `titlesec`) for more functionality.  (For example, if you had written your own `\MakeSentenceCase`, that may have been a bit too much work—a lot of code means a lot of room for small errors.)