# How to get sentence case in section titles without biblatex

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I would like to change my section titles into sentence case just like the solution here:
[How to make sections into sentence case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120406/how-to-make-sections-into-sentence-case)

The `titlesec` package is already included in my document to modify section title formatting, so this seems like a good solution.  The problem is that I am using a `book` class and require the `chapterbib` package.  When I include the `biblatex` package to use the `\MakeSentenceCase` macro, it tells me that it's incompatible with `chapterbib` and fails to compile.

Is there an alternative method I can use to access `\MakeSentenceCase` or create a similar macro for use in the `\titleformat` command?

Comment: It seems like I could modify this solution, but for sentence case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103838/converting-text-to-title-case  I don't know enough about the basic LaTeX commands to implement it, though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\MakeSentenceCase` is for uniformizing titles in a bibliography. For your section titles, just type them as *you* want them to appear.

Comment: @egreg I agree this is usually the easiest solution.  But, for my dissertation I have consistently used title case on almost 100 headings and subheadings.  LaTeX should be able to switch all section titles to sentence case to satisfy a new formatting requirement -- in my opinion, one of the major strengths of LaTeX is its programmability.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`stringstrings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand\SentenceCase[1]{%
  \caselower[e]{#1}%
  \capitalize[q]{\thestring}%
}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\SentenceCase{#1}\thestring}

\begin{document}

\section{test section one}
\section{TesT SectION Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works very nicely.  Is there a way to have `stringstrings` reproduce acronyms or maths in titles?  For example, `\section{A Title Including $\mu$}` or `\section{Another Title with {ACRONYMS}}`.

Comment: @jeg Not easily; notice that `\MakeSentenceCase` has the same problem.

Comment: @jeg give me some hours; I'll try to provide a version which does what you require.